# How do I load an audio file in videojs while using videojs-record?

Tags: video.js, videojs-record

Here is my plight, I have been tasked with making sure that I can load an audio file in a videojs player with the plugins videojs-wavesurfer and videojs-record installed, so far so good, however when I try to use player.src() and player.load() the waveform of the audio, as well as the controls of the player appear for but one second, then instantly dissapears and the audio unloads, how can I load an audio file to the player?